# ld: Undefined symbols: in C

Tags: c, ld

This is my function.c file.

```c
int max(int a, int b) {
    return a>b? a:b;
}
```

This is my head.h file.

```c
#pragma once 
extern int max(int a,int b);
```

This is my main.c file.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "0703head.h"
 
int main() {
   printf("%d\n", max(10,20));
   return 0;
}
```

And this is the problem.

```
ld: Undefined symbols:
  
_max, referenced from:

_main in 0701main-5801ea.o

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I don't know how to deal with this error.

Comment: Welcome to SO. How do you build your program? Please add your compiler command line to the question.

Comment: gcc main.c funciton.c -o program.exe

Comment: ``#include "0703head.h"`` ?? This seems to be an error

Comment: Remove 0703 from the include directive.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The error you're encountering typically occurs due to a linking issue. It seems that the linker cannot find the definition for the max function when compiling your main.c file.
Make sure you're compiling and linking all the necessary files together. You can compile both function.c and main.c and then link them together.

- Compile function.c into an object file

  **gcc -c function.c -o function.o**
- Compile main.c into an object file

  **gcc -c main.c -o main.o**
- Link the object files to create an executable

  **gcc function.o main.o -o my_program**

Replace the

```
gcc
```

with your compiler command

Comment: It is not required to use extra commands for compilation and linking, but the main statements regarding compiling both source files is still correct.